# How to flip an image in Qt?

Tags: c++, qt, qml, qlabel

I found [that video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eZyV4f9r5m8) on Youtube. It shows how to flip something called QML Flipable. I'm completely unfamiliar with QML so I have the following questions:

1) Is it possible to flip an ordinary QLabel like this? If yes how do I do that?

2) If it's not possible then how do I add that Flipable entity to my QMainWindow?

Thanks, everyone

Answer (score 1):

There's no convenient way to do this. Desktop OS's don't provide this functionality.

One option is to use QGraphicsView. You can add widgets to a QGraphicsScene using `QGraphicsScene::addWidget()`, for example, and then transform the view the way you want.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the [QGraphicsPixmap](http://doc.qt.digia.com/qt/qgraphicspixmapitem.html) with your image , set the rotation center with setTransformOriginPoint and animate the transformation matrix with [QProertyAnimation](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qpropertyanimation.html)

Answer (score 0):

Quick google search points me to a blog [article](http://kunalmaemo.blogspot.com/2011/03/flipping-rotating-view-animation-in-qml.html) where author of the video (Kunal Parmar) describing how this particular effect was done.

Comment: i've seen that article. it explains how to deal with Flipable but it doesn't explain how to add that Flipable as a widget or something like a widget